# Web site for Update Manager changes / description

Tags: updates, ubuntu-website

The Changes / Description tabs in the Update Manager are very useful to get a concise explanation for each update, but I only use the shell to update now (`sudo sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get autoclean"`). Is there some web site where I can subscribe to a feed for these upgrades? That would be more convenient than going back to the GUI or trying to figure out after the fact where all the information is on my local box.

**Edit**

To summarize:

- A **chronological** list of **all updates** to **all packages**, not one list per package. In other words, exactly like in the Update Manager.
- Preferably with about the same amount of information as is shown in the Update Manager, but with **links** to bug reports, VCS log, diffs and other relevant information.
- Preferably retrievable as a **web feed**, to be able to read it in a more sane way than repeatedly checking a web site manually.

This would be an awesome way to keep track of the updates without having to read them at install time, and with the possibility to dig into lots more detail when wanted. Who knows, maybe it could even lead to more community participation, since it is essentially a furthering of the existing style of openness?

Answer (score 1):

To get a changelog for a package on the command-line, run:

```
apt-get changelog package-name
```

There is a mailing list available which contains information about updates packages https://lists.ubuntu.com/#Package+Upload+and+Automatic+Notification+Lists

For previous updates, see the mailing list archives. Natty's archive page is available at https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/natty-changes/

The two mentioned links provides updates on all package updates, not just the packages you're using.

Comment: Interesting stuff, but the command line was specifically **not** what I asked for, and the list does not correspond to the actual updates. For example, I just installed a whole bunch of updates, including one "unity 3.8.12-0ubuntu1", but I couldn't find a reference to that in the Natty-changes list.

Comment: You must have overlooked it then, `apt-get changelog unity` shows me clearly "unity (3.8.12-0ubuntu1) natty-proposed; urgency=low" ([archived mail](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/natty-changes/2011-April/011808.html)). You didn't say that you want a non-CLI way: "That would be more convenient than going back to the GUI [..]".

Comment: I guess the original text was unclear. The "figure out after the fact where all the information is on my local box" refers to this sort of commands. The first reason not to use it is that I want a sequential list of changes *on the entire system*, not for a single package, and the second is that I would like a web interface to have the relevant links to things like more detailed information and diffs.